# Googlemaps circle not appearing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry

I'm having trouble getting a circle to appear on my map, but I'm not getting any errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.0342375, -77.3066405),
             zoom: 8,
             mapTypeControl: false,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, //style below will be 'shift worker' from snazzy maps
             styles: [{"stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"gamma":1}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.place_of_worship","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.place_of_worship","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":50},{"gamma":0},{"hue":"#50a5d1"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#333333"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"weight":0.5},{"color":"#333333"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"gamma":1},{"saturation":50}]}] 

        };
        var mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

     var map = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

     $(document).ready(function() {
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        var populationOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.0342375, -77.3066405),
          radius: 84482
        };
        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope in Javascript bit you.

The `mymap` variable is what you need to use for the CircleOptions `map` property.  However it goes out of scope with your initialize function.  Your `map` variable in the anonymous function is just a DIV DOM element, not a `google.maps.Map` instance.

Simplified working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/stevejansen/H5bRg/

There is no reason to combine jQuery's document#ready event handler with `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`.  They both handle the same DOM event.  Just stick with one or the other.  It's confusing to use both.